# How can i add view to a UITextView Object

Tags: iphone

i have a UITextView object and i want to load a label object or a set of label object over it but i dont have a view property for UITextView.The only thing i have is subViews property in UIView class which is parent class of UITextView.How should i really go about it...

Answer (score 0):

There is a method on `UIView` called `addSubview`, which takes a `UIView` object as a parameter.

`UITextView` inherits from `UIView`, so you can call `[textView addSubview:someView];`.